# How to share information between entities in an ER diagram?

Tags: database, erd

In this case will the employee have the information about the rental date, so as to send a reminder? If not, how do I execute the connection?

[image: ER diagram]

Comment: Is that a flowchart of some kind of a data diagram? Please provide a clearer background to your question.

Comment: It's a sample of an ER diagram.I want the employee to send a reminder to the customer when the rental date is due.So should i connect the <employee> entity with the <RENTS> relationship set for him to know the information?Or must i do something else?

Answer (score 0):

Make the diagram like this to show that the employee is given information about the rents. Information about the attributes of the rents relationship is shared between the customer entity and the employee entity.

[image]

This diagram could be made more detailed if more information about the database is provided, especially if the information is in the form of code.